# Focus/unfocus an input on range slider handler's use

Tags: javascript, forms, input, range

I have a form where the inputs values are controlled by range sliders. There's a calculation every time there's a new entry on each input which operates on focusout.

Though, the calculation doesn't work when only the range sliders are used. Is there a way to focus the inputs while using the range sliders? I can't change the way of calculation, because, it's on all the inputs. So, it has to be this way.

My form is bigger, but, here's an example of what I have:

```
<label class="va1">Option a price 1:<input id="a1" type="number"/></label>
<input type="range" id="slider-a1" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0"><br>
<label class="va2">Option a price 2:<input id="a2" type="number"/></label>
<input type="range" id="slider-a2" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0"><br>
<label>Result:</label><input id="a5" type="text" name="total_amt"/>
```

And here's the JS:

```
var opt_1 = document.getElementById("slider-a1");
opt_1.oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("a1").value = opt_1.value;}
var opt_2 = document.getElementById("slider-a2");
opt_2.oninput = function() {
  document.getElementById("a2").value = opt_2.value;}

calculate = function(){
   var optiona1, optiona2, resultss;
   optiona1 = Number(document.getElementById("a1").value);
   optiona2 = Number(document.getElementById("a2").value);
   resultss = parseInt(optiona1)+parseInt(optiona2);
   document.getElementById('a5').value = resultss;}
   $('input[type=number]').on('focusout', calculate);
```

Comment: All you need to do, is call `calculate` inside both of your range slider input handlers …

Comment: (Explicitly _triggering_ the focusout event would also be an option, but that is not even needed here.)

Comment: As I precised, this is just an example. There're many calculations on my original form. My question, is how I would be able to focus and unfocus the inputs when range sliders handlers are used.

Comment: I don’t think messing with the input field focus is a good idea to begin with, that is likely to interfere with using the range sliders. Does simply triggering the focusout event not work for you? (To be clear, talking about https://api.jquery.com/trigger/ here.)

Comment: Well, actually, my form has 32 inputs, and the calculation operates on focusing each input. For UI reasons, we decided to add range sliders. The problem is, when people use only the range sliders, the input values aren't taken as they aren't focused, so, the calculation isn't made. I don't know, if it's really clear.

Comment: So go and _trigger_ the focusout event then, when the values of the range sliders change …